# How to know how to translate -たり form

Tags: grammar

I read that `-たり form` can either be translated as "**and**" or "**or**", and that it indicates **no particular chronological order**.

My question is, **how do you know when which is which?**

For example, I came across these sentences:

> - シャワーをあびたり、晩{ばん}ご飯{はん}を食{た}べたりします。
>
> *I take a shower **or** I have dinner.*
>
> - 夏{なつ}にはウインドサーフィンをしたり、サーフィンをしたりします。
>
> *In summer, I do windsurfing **and** surf.*

Why were they not translated as:

> *I take a shower **and** I have dinner.*
>
> *In summer I do windsurfing **or** surf.*

Does that have something to do with use `-て form` for listing actions rather than `-たり form`?

Comment: Doesn't 「XたりYたりする」mean 'do things like X and Y'?

Comment: I'm not sure but it sounds like it could be used to say that

Comment: @AeonAkechi : Maybe you're right, and maybe the best/safe way to translate it would be not to use any word, like "I do this, that, etc…" (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate it as “do things like windsurfing or surfing” but the context generally communicates the meaning. “We filled the long summer months of our childhood with surfing, hiking, and bonfires on the beach” is the kind of thing that wd get translated with 〜たり forms in Japanese.

Remember, real language has context. Single-sentence examples in textbooks are not real language.

Comment: So, are you saying that both translations are correct? Or maybe that none of them trully render the nuance of 〜たり and that we shouldn't use either "or" or "and" to translate it?

Comment: Both translations are correct, with the right context.